# How to update scoring.py file in deployed azure ml web services without changing the scoring url

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

i have deployed a model in ACI , Now i want to change the  Scoring.py file of my webservice. i Have tried below code but its giving me error

```
inf_conf = InferenceConfig(entry_script="dcp_pi_main_scoring.py")

#service_name = 'binary-test'
# Retrieve existing service.
service = Webservice(name='binary-test', workspace=ws)
service.update(inference_config=inf_conf)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

Above Code giving me error as:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Can anyone please help me in this

Comment: Can you please add more details about the entry script file and that you are trying to update.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. okey i will try this one and did you see any wrong in above code and whats the error is about

Answer (score 0):

When deploying your inference script, beyond the entry script (score.py), inferenceConfig also let you specify source directory that include the entry script as well as all other python code (packages as a subfolder in the source directory that has its own init.py, or plain python script files modules).

The score.py script can directly import from them because the whole folder including score.py and all other folders will be available at the inference running environment.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.inferenceconfig?view=azure-ml-py